# How to precompile handlebars templates using webpack?

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I have below webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HandlebarsPlugin = require('precompile-handlebars');

module.exports = {

      plugins: [
        new HandlebarsPlugin([
            {
                inputDir: "src/main/resources/static/templates",
                outputFile: "src/main/resources/static/js/compiled-templates.js"
            }
        ])
    ],
}
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
     "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",


  "devDependencies": {
    "precompile-handlebars": "^1.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

When  I do npm run dev or npm run build, it does not generate precompiled handlebar template. I am simply using webpack to precompile handlebars templates  and nothing else. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader) with `precompileOptions`?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in hacky way! Webpack can generate static html from templates as usual, but for dynamic parts in html (like async DB data, async filters, etc) we can **replace syntax tags** for this parts and later process bundled html file on server to pass to it data and async filters.

#### Example:

For my template engine "TWIG" I replace default `{%...%}` tag to `<%...%>`, etc. And processed templates with default tags by webpack.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is static webpack part with default tag: {% include "./test.twig"%}</p>
    <p>This is dynamic part with custom tag: <% book|getDetails %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And after webpack generated bundle file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is static webpack part with default tag: "THIS IS STATIC PART"</p>
    <p>This is dynamic part with custom tag: <% book|getDetails %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And now I can render/pre-render this file on my server side, by set default syntax tag to `<%...%>`.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is static webpack part with default tag: "THIS IS STATIC PART"</p>
    <p>This is dynamic part with custom tag: "THIS IS DYNAMIC BOOK NAME"</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think using webpack to just compile handlebar templates is an overkill. You can compile them simply using NodeJS command line.

Fire up the NodeJS command prompt and do this

```
npm -g install handlebars
```

Then run the following handlebars command which will take all the templates in your templates folder and combine them into one file named templates.js.

```
handlebars js/templates/ -f js/templates/templates.js
```

More details [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html).

Hope this helps ....